# Any way to inspect 3g traffic?

Tags: networking, cellular-network

I have a device that uses a 3G sim card to send data over Internet, but we need some way to inspect the traffic it sends. It's an IoT device and we need to create a server that processes the data it sends, but first, we need to see which data is sending.

Does anyone have an idea on how we can inspect what the device is sending? There's no option to set up a proxy on the device, so that's not an option.

Do you know if there's any way to create a custom APN that forwards everything to the real APN?

Answer (score 0):

There is always Wireshark.

Here is a detail tutorial , hope i helped

https://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-tutorial-analyzing-gsm-with-airprobe-and-wireshark/